# Why is the array empty every time on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, clone

So basically every time I click on the icon '.favorite i' it should add an object to my array. If I click the first time it adds the parent div to the array, but on the second time it deletes the first one and grabs the last parent div.

I'm working with three tabs called 'Monday', 'Tuesday' and 'Favorites'. I have a toggle icon which is an empty heart at start 'favorite i'. If I'm in Monday and click on the icon, the empty heart turns to be filled out and its parent is cloned and added to the '#fav' tab. When this happens the clone is saved to local storage. So if people refresh the page, they can still see their preferences.

When the heart is clicked in one of those cloned divs that specific div is removed from '#fav' and will also have to be removed from the array and local storage too.

To conclude, I need to save each cloned div into an array/local storage and then be able to delete each one of those from the array when these are  removed from the #fav tab.

How to overcome this issue? Many thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="tabs_main">

      <div class="col-md-5"><a data-target="#mon" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab">Monday</a></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><a data-target="#tue" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab">Tuesday</a></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><a data-target="#fav" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>

   </div>

   <div class="tab-content">

     <div class="tab-pane active" id="mon">
       <br>
       <div class="spaces">
         <div class="box-container">
           <div class="box not-selected" id="box1">
           <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         </div>
         <div class="box-container">
           <div class="box not-selected" id="box2">
           <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane" id="tue">
       <br>
       <div class="spaces">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane" id="fav">
        <br>
     </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('div.tab-pane').on('click', '.favorite', function(e) {
  var add = $(this).parent().parent();
  add.each(function(){

    if ($(add.find('.not-selected .favorite i').hasClass('fa-heart'))) {

      var boxContent = $(add).clone(true, true);
      var showHide = $(boxContent).find(".session").addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected');
      var get = $(boxContent).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
      $(boxContent).unwrap();

      var tempArray = [];

      tempArray.push(get);

      var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(get);

      var parseString = $.parseJSON(myJSONString);

      var finalString = myJSONString.replace(/\r?\\n/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/^\[(.+)\]$/,'$1').replace (/(^")|("$)/g, '');

      var final = localStorage.setItem('sessions', finalString);

      $("#fav").append(tempArray);

    };

  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/itsfranhere/nbLLc3L0/44/

Comment: I don't completely understand your code, but if you want the `tempArray` to survive between first and second click, you cannot declare it inside of the function (because that will make a fresh empty array every time).

Comment: Please provide all relevant HTML code.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, I appreciate it. Do you think you have enough information to help? @DanPhilip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **question title** is quite clear...
But your question itself and the code you provide prevents anyone to answer with full assurance.

[Here is what the provided code produces](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dzxEvP?editors=1010), as an attempt to reproduce.

Now if I do not bother that code, which I think no one can deduct what it should do exactly...
Your question in title can be can answered by:

**Simple!** You declare (using `var`) the  `tempArray` at every `click`.
That is why it do not retain the information (whatever it is supposed to retain) of the previous `click`.

I'm not "satisfied" of this answer to you... So if this do not answers completely your issue, please edit your question with more details. Feel free to fork the CodePen to make it look more like your project.

---

**EDIT**

From what I get of your script, you want to save "favorited" divs to localstorage. This implies you also have to remove them from localstorage and favorites tab if one is "unfavorited".

Also, you use `id` on "to be cloned" element. Be extremely cautious with this. An `id` **has to be** unique. So if the `id` is usefull (which was not obvious in the provided code), ensure you make it unique when you clone the element.

I improved you attempt to remove spaces and line feeds in what is to be saved.

Another good advise I have to give you is to use significative variable names in your code. Make your code speak by itself. Readability helps!

Here is your code, updated to do what is mentionned above. Have a close look to comments in code.

```
var tempArray = [];

// Clones
$('div.tab-pane').on('click', '.favorite', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Elements we play with... Having significative variable names.
  var heartLink = $(this);
  var box = heartLink.parent('.box');
  var container = box.parent('.box-container');
  var favoriteTab = $("#fav .spaces");

  // I don't know what is the use for those 3 lines below.
  var idFind = box.attr("id");
  var idComplete = ('#' + idFind);
  console.log(idComplete);

  //TOGGLE FONT AWESOME ON CLICK
  heartLink.find('i').toggleClass('fa-heart fa-heart-o'); // .selected or not, you need those 2 classes to toggle.
  box.toggleClass("selected not-selected"); // Toggle selected and not-selected classes

  // Clone div
  var boxContent = container.clone(true, true);

  // Change the id
  var thisID = boxContent.attr("id")+"_cloned";
  boxContent.attr("id", thisID);

  // Get the html to be saved in localstorage
  var get = boxContent.wrap('<p>').parent().html();
  get = get.replace(/\r?\n/g, "").replace(/>\s*</g, "><"); // remove line feeds and spaces
  console.log(get);
  boxContent.unwrap();

  // Decide to add or remove
  if(box.hasClass("selected")){
    console.log("Add to array")
    tempArray.push(get);

    // Add to favorites tab
    favoriteTab.append(boxContent);

  }else{
    console.log("Remove from array");
    var index = tempArray.indexOf(get);
    tempArray.splice(index);

    // Remove from favorite tab
    favoriteTab.find("#"+thisID).remove();
  }

  // Save
  localStorage.setItem('sessions', tempArray.join(""));

});

// Append item if localstorage is detected
if (localStorage["sessions"]) {
  $("#fav .spaces").append(localStorage["sessions"]);
  console.log( localStorage.getItem('sessions') );
}
```

[**Updated CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MEgQpV?editors=0011)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do understand now better the issue.. but still don't know how to solve it.

I hope this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/itsfranhere/nbLLc3L0/44/

Comment: If you define the issue more, you will help me (and others) to answer you. I do not get what you try to do at all, for the moment.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when user clicks on the heart?

Comment: mmm... Okay, I [updated my CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VzoJYp?editors=1011) from your Fiddle code and CSS. I think I get what you try to do. But... What a twistted code! For the moment, I just commented your code, without any change except the addition of some console.logs. Have a look and try to clean that up a bit. Then We'll work on the remaining issues. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience.. I know it must be something out of this world but as you can imagine, I'm new to js, so I really appreciate your help here. I'm in a very tight deadline, so if you could help on this asap that would be great. I've done my best: https://jsfiddle.net/nbLLc3L0/48/

Comment: Here is an improvement of your code. I at least add/remove items from favorites, and the localstorage is working. See answer edit.

Comment: I can’t thank you enough! This is exactly what I was looking to achieve. If you ever come to Portugal let me know and I’ll pay you a few beers :D

Comment: One last quick question. How to remove those commas (separators) in the array? Join()?

Comment: Yes! You can use `.join(",")` to remove the comas. ;) I never refuse a beer!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! So, at the end I have to convert the object to a string and parse it, is that right? At least is what people are saying to me. Then I could use the join method, since it returns a new string. I couldn't make it work yet, but will try a few more times

Comment: I edited my answer about where to place the `.join(",")`... It should work, but I did not test.

Comment: Thank a lot, but here's what I get: TypeError: localStorage.sessions.join is not a function

Comment: haha... See ? That's what always happen when I do not test my answers... lol! It is working now. I edited the answer AND the last Fiddle (v4)

Answer (score 1):

Don't save `div` elements in localStorage. I recommend you use an object constructor function like below to create a unique object for each [whatever] pushing these into an array then to localStorage in a try block.

`localStorage.setItem('myobjects', JSON.stringify(myobjects));`

```
// Object Constructor Functions
function Myobject(id, username, password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.type = 'credential';
}

function duplicate(id,obj){
    var result = false;
    obj.forEach( function (arrayItem){
        if (arrayItem.id == id){
          result = true;
        }
    }); 
    return result;
}


function deleteObject(type, id){ 
    var obj = {};
    if (type === 'foo') {
        obj = myobjectwhatever;
        deleteThis(obj);
        //save  to local storage
        try {
            localStorage.setItem('myobject', JSON.stringify(myobjects));
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    else if (type === 'bar') {
       //...
    }

    function deleteThis(o){
        try {
            for (var i = 0, iLen = o.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                if (o[i].id === id) {
                    o.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not sure how to adapt this 'strategy' to my code but will give it a try :)

Comment: understood. the advantage of creating object constructors is so you have a scheme to follow, i.e., your object constructor called `FavoriteObject` (note the first letter is cap'd) is standardized with, for example, name, make, model, color, whateverProperty). Then you can use basic if/then logic against individual instances of objects, say, `if(myObject.color === 'red'){do whatever}`. Hope that helps see [Working w Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Very interesting indeed! Thanks a lot, I'll start looking for more info about this. Take care :)