# How to remember current toggle state in this example after page refresh with local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, save, toggle, storage

I have 3 tabs: 'Monday', 'Tuesday' and 'Favorites'. Each tab contains boxes with an empty heart at start ('.favorite i'). I want to save the current toggle class after refresh.

Toggle:

```
heartLink.find('i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart'); // .selected or not
```

I've started with:

```
if (heartLink.find('i').hasClass('fa-heart-o')) {
  localStorage.setItem('displayIcon', 0);
 } else {
  localStorage.setItem('displayIcon', 1);
 }
```

And then I know I will need something similar to this but don't know how to do it..

To make clear: I want to save the current state of each specific heart. I don't one icon to affect all boxes.

```
var showIconToggle = localStorage.getItem('displayIcon');
if (showIconToggle == 'true') {
    // some code
}
```

HTML:

```
   <section id="speakers-programme">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="tabs_main">

          <div class="col-md-5"><a data-target="#mon" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab">Monday</a></div>
          <div class="col-md-5"><a data-target="#tue" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab">Tuesday</a></div>
          <div class="col-md-2"><a data-target="#fav" class="btn active" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>

       </div>

       <div class="tab-content">

         <div class="tab-pane active" id="mon">
           <br>
           <div class="spaces">
             <div class="box-container">
               <div class="box not-selected" id="box1">
               <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-container">
             <div class="box not-selected" id="box2">
               <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </div>
            </div>
         </div>

        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tue">
           <br>
           <div class="spaces">
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane active" id="fav">
           <br>
           <div class="spaces">
           </div>
        </div>


        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```

JS:

```
$('div.tab-pane').on('click', '.favorite', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

        var heartLink = $(this);

      //TOGGLE FONT AWESOME ON CLICK
      heartLink.find('i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart'); // .selected or not, you need those 2 classes to toggle.

      if (heartLink.find('i').hasClass('fa-heart-o')) {
        localStorage.setItem('displayIcon', 0);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('displayIcon', 1);
      }


});

var showIconToggle = localStorage.getItem('displayIcon');
   if (showIconToggle == 'true') {
     // some code here
}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/itsfranhere/1q93a6x1/9/

Comment: you need to save it in 3 different keys inside the localStorage or you can use a bitmask to save it in one variable. It depends on your style and knowlege.

Comment: Thank you for your response @JoshuaK Can you show me one way of doing this? As I've mentioned, I can't seem to achieve the result I want. Take a look at the fiddle if you can please.

Comment: Added a solution for storing it in one variable. In this way you don't need an id for each heart and the localStorage stays clean and is not full of state-variables for each heart. (just an addon to the given and acceped answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question folowing up [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146758/why-is-the-array-empty-every-time-on-click/46147123#46147123).

To save your not cloned element states (favorited or not), add this:

At the end of the `click` handler, save the classes for the clicked `i`.

```
// save this current toggle state
localStorage.setItem(box.attr("id"), $(this).find("i").attr("class"));
console.log($(this).find("i").attr("class"));
```

On page load, before loading the favorites from localStorage, apply those saved classes:

```
// Load heart's element states
$(".box").each(function(){
  console.log( $(this).attr("id") );
  console.log( localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id")) );

  if(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id")) != null){
    $(this).find("i").removeClass().addClass( localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id")) );
  }
});
```

[**CodePen v5**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bobjdv?editors=1011)

Comment: superb, This is the best answer for sure! Now one last issue apart.. everything works well but if I refresh the page with localstorage I get some problems. I'll explain.. If I'm in the website for the 1st time and I go to  'Monday' tab and clone a few boxes, they all go to #fav as supposed.. and if I click in any of those filled hearts in 'Monday' the clone gets removed, all fine. When I refresh the browser and do the same, it doesn't remove the clone and adds a new clone to the #fav tab and if I'm in the #fav tab, where I have 2 boxes, when clicking in one filled heart, the array is erased

Comment: I look forward for your input on this matter, this is really what's missing on my project and then I'll be able to finish it. Reply asap. Thank you once again!

Comment: I've created a new question to try to solve this issue.. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167293/why-is-persisting-data-not-working-as-it-should

Comment: I see... Quick answer. That is because on page reload, the "cloned-saved" elements aren't in array. The array is empty at this point. Remember they where loaded from localStorage.

Comment: hum.. is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, you need to store each heart individually.

Here's how I'd do it: in the HTML, give each heart an `id`. When a heart is clicked, save the new state in localstorage under `favorite:id` where `id` is replaced with the heart's `id`.

When the page loads, grab every heart on the page, and look up its favorite status using its `id`.

Example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/1q93a6x1/10/

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use just one variable you can use a bitmask.

**Theory**
If you want to save 5 states, the binary value has 5 digits. In decimal it's a variable between 0 and 31.

First the easy part: **How can I read out a state?**
Let's say the actual state is 31 (11111) and we want to know the value of the third digit. How can we do this? Just bitwise and the state with a bitmask where all digits are zero except the digit we want to know:

```
11111 & 00100 = 00100
```

If the result is greater than zero, this digit is set.

*To create the bitmask just shift a 1 by the amount of digits you want to take a look: `1 << 2 = 00100`*

Now the "though" part: **Setting and unsetting a bit**

To set a bit you have to bitwise or the bitmask:

```
00000 | 00100 = 00100
```

If this bit is already set... no problem it will be set afterwards.

If you want to unset a bit it's a bit tricky: You can xor the bitmask, but if the bit wasn't set before it's now set.

```
00100 ^ 00100 = 00000, BUT
00000 ^ 00100 = 00100 (now it's set. It's a trigger, not an unset)
```

The way you can be sure is: create the inverted bitmask and use bitwise and:

```
00100 & (00100 ^ (11111)) = 00100 & 11011 = 00000, AND
00000 & (00100 ^ (11111)) = 00000 & 11011 = 00000
```

**Now let's code**

For this you take the position of the heart in the dom and use it as an exponent to the base of 2. If you want to set a heart, add this value, if you want to remove it subtract it (Or in bitwise operations: | (or) for adding and & (and) for removing).

saving the actual state:

```
var $heartLinks = $('.favorite');
var $heartLink = $(this);
var position = $heartLinks.index($heartLink); // this is the position inside the bitmask

var actualBitmask = parseInt(localStorage.displayIcon || '0', 10);
var bit = (1 << position);
var invertedBit = bit ^ ((1 << $heartLinks.length) - 1);
if(!$heartLink.find('i').hasClass('fa-heart-o'))
    actualBitmask |= bit;
else
    actualBitmask &= invertedBit;
localStorage.setItem('displayIcon', actualBitmask);
```

and calling it when site is ready:

```
var showIconToggle = localStorage.displayIcon || 0;
$heartLinks.map(function(idx) {
  if((showIconToggle & Math.pow(2,idx)) > 0)
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
});
```

working [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1q93a6x1/12/)